# Views one to many relationship, display many records in columns

Tags: 6, views

I have a View with a one to many relationship. ID and Session are in my main table, and "mark"'s are rows in a custom table. When I look up a single ID, I get this result because of the 'many' results in the custom table.

ID | Session     | mark

15 | Spring 2013 | 16

15 | Spring 2013 | 3

15 | Spring 2013 | 5.5

My desired result is:

ID | Session     | mark 1 | mark 2 | mark 3

15 | Spring 2013 | 16 | 3 | 5.5

Comment: depends if you want separated columns for each mark, or if all marks in the same column is allowed ?

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [viewsfield](https://drupal.org/project/viewfield) module? You can try solving your problem by creating two views A and B, such that -

1. View A excepts an argument 'ID' and lists all the marks associated with it, by having only the 'marks' field included for display/output.
2. View B has an ID field, a session field, and a viewsfield. In this third field the view A is embedded.

I hope this helps. I have not tried this, but I am reasonably sure it should help if the module is doing what it promises to do.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use a custom php method inside each mark column

See [Views php module](https://drupal.org/project/views_php)

Your method could return the right value based on the delta index :

```
// in the custom php field (view)
return _my_method( $data->field_mark, 1 ); //(value, delta)

//do it 3 times, in each column
return _my_method( $data->field_mark, 2 ); //(value, delta)
return _my_method( $data->field_mark, 3 ); //(value, delta)


// in your module
function _my_method( $marks, delta ){
  return isset( $marks->['und'][ delta ]['value'] ) ? $marks->['und'][ delta ]['value'] : NULL;
}
```

Comment: i know the module above is still in dev, but it's a suggestion of code

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried grouping your fields under the Format settings?

Comment: I just tried "Use grouping" under "Advanced settings", which provides a wrench on all of my fields but "Group results together" on "mark" doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try grouping on ID